# selectOneRadio PrimeFaces Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

```
        <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="70" styleClass="ui-center">   

            <h:panelGrid columns="6" cellpadding="10" >
                <p:selectOneRadio id="trie" value="#{consultation.trie}" >  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="X" itemValue="1" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Y" itemValue="3" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Z" itemValue="4" />
                    <p:ajax update="tables1"/>  
                </p:selectOneRadio>
             </h:panelGrid>

        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit  position="center" >   
            <h:panelGroup id="tables1">

                <p:dataTable value="#{bean.List1}" rendered="#{bean.trie==3}">

                </p:dataTable>

                <p:dataTable value="#{bean.List1}" rendered="#{bean.trie==1}">

                </p:dataTable>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:layoutUnit>
     </form>
</p:layout>
```

I should change id="trie" twice to update tables1, I have this probleme only when i run my apps for the first time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to primefaces_user_guide,a layout unit must have it’s own form. You should used below following instead.

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
    <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="100">
        <h:form>
            <h:outputText value="Left Pane" />
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <h:form>
            <h:outputText value="Right Pane" />
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```